# Entities inheriting from generic interfaces in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, interface

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IInitializable
{
    void Initialize ();
}

public interface IPersistXmlElementTo
{
    XmlElement ToXmlElement (XmlDocument document);
}

public interface IPersistXmlElement<T>:
    IPersistXmlElementTo,
    IInitializable
{
    T FromXmlElement (XmlElement element);
}

public interface IPersistXmlDocumentTo:
    IPersistXmlElementTo
{
    XmlDocument ToXmlDocument ();
}

public interface IPersistXmlDocument<T>:
    IPersistXmlDocumentTo,
    IPersistXmlElement<T>,
    IInitializable
{
    T FromXmlDocument (XmlDocument document);
}

public interface ICloneable<T>
    where T: ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone ();
}

public interface ICopyable<T>:
    IInitializable,
    ICloneable<T>
    where T: ICopyable<T>
{
    T CopyFrom (T source);
    T CopyTo (T destination);
}

public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    byte [] TimeStamp { get; set; }
    DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    DateTime DateTimeModified { get; set; }
}
```

All entity classes inherit from `IEntity` at the moment. I'd now like IEntity to inherit from the interfaces above. That means converting IEntity to a generic interface. Something like:

```
public interface IEntity<T>:
    IPersistXmlDocument<T>,
    IPersistXmlElement<T>,
    ICloneable<T>,
    ICopyable<T>,
    IInitializable
    where T: IEntity<T>
```

I've had trouble with EF while inheriting from classes but interfaces seem to work ok so far. Are there any gotchas to look out for? Any special configurations in EF required to switch from `Entity: IEntity` to `Entity: IEntity<Entity>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the generic interfaces had no effect on EF whatsoever.